# Azure Functions - .NET 8 isolated - logging no longer showing up in Azure Portal Invocation Traces

Tags: c#, logging, azure-functions, .net-8.0, azure-functions-isolated

When writing Azure Functions in C#, I find it very useful that I am able to output some selected messages to a logger, and that those messages show up in the "Invocation Traces" in the Azure Portal:

This has worked just fine, from the Azure Function v1 up to those written against .NET 6.0 Isolated.

[image: Azure Portal Invocation Trace Display up to .NET 6.0]

But now, I've created a few more new functions, using .NET 8.0 Isolated, and now it seems, outputting those log/trace messages no longer works....

[image: Azure Portal Invocation Trace Display now in .NET 8.0]

What has changed so fundamentally that my logging no longer shows up in the Azure Portal?

Right now, I'm injecting the `ILoggerFactory` into my Azure Function class and creating an `ILogger<T>` from it (where `T` is the type of my function class).

```
public class MyAzureFunction
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _factory;
    private readonly ILogger<MyAzureFunction> _logger;

    public MyAzureFunction(IConfiguration configuration, ILoggerFactory factory)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _factory = factory;
        _logger = factory.CreateLogger<MyAzureFunction>();
    }
    
    // Actual Azure Function code follows here
}
```

I also tried to use the `FunctionContext` as an injectable parameter to my Azure Function method that gets triggered (by a HTTP call, or a timer) and create the `ILogger<T>` from that:

```
[Function("MyAzureFunction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post")] HttpRequest req, 
                                     FunctionContext executionContext)
{
    ILogger _logger = executionContext.GetLogger(nameof(MyAzureFunction));
    
    _logger.LogInformation("My Azure Function was HTTP triggered");
    
    // rest of the function code
}
```

Neither of these approaches seems to work - none of my own custom messages, output by `_logger.LogInformation`, actually show up in the Azure Portal "Invocation Traces" display.

I've also played around with various settings in the `_host.json` - but to no avail - and not knowing exactly *where* the problem lies, and how to fix it, this all seems like a bit of a messy "trial & error" without really understanding what the issue is, and how to solve it.

Can anyone enlighten me? What am I missing? What has changed with .NET 8.0 support in Azure Functions? How can I get my own custom messages to show up in the Azure Invocation Traces again?

Comment: Can you please share the code which you are using in .NET6 isolated function to log the custom messages?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin: exactly the same as in the .NET 8 version - injecting `ILoggerFactory` into class, creating internal `ILogger<T> _logger`  in that class, and using `_logger.LogInformation(".....")` to write out messages

Comment: Try to use `private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

public Function1(ILogger<Function1> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}` in your **function.cs** file and then use the logger in this [way](https://i.imgur.com/Uwwggny.png). Your **Program.cs** file should look like [this](https://i.imgur.com/jBtTVr1.png)

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin: sorry, I tried it - but that doesn't make any difference whatsover

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should call `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()` and `ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights()` during service configuration in your `Program.cs` file:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
    
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Also note that by default, the Application Insights SDK adds a logging filter that instructs the logger to capture only warnings and more severe logs. If you want to disable this behavior, remove the filter rule as part of service configuration:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(services => {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.Services.Configure<LoggerFilterOptions>(options =>
        {
            LoggerFilterRule defaultRule = options.Rules.FirstOrDefault(rule => rule.ProviderName
                == "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ApplicationInsights.ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider");
            if (defaultRule is not null)
            {
                options.Rules.Remove(defaultRule);
            }
        });
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

Comment: Thanks - that seems to have done the trick - thank you very much indeed ! Any docs where these changes have been announced / documented?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows#application-insights

Comment: This is required for .NET 8 and Azure Functions v4.

Comment: I am confused by this statement from MS: "The Functions host and the isolated process worker have separate configuration for log levels, etc. Any Application Insights configuration in host.json will not affect the logging from the worker, and similarly, configuration made in your worker code will not impact logging from the host. You need to apply changes in both places if your scenario requires customization at both layers." Does it mean, I still need to modify the default host.json file and add LogLevel configuraiton there as well?

Comment: @OliverNilsen The host and the worker are now in separate processes. Logging from the host includes things like "Executing 'MyFunction' (Reason=....", whereas the worker is from your code.